# What coroutine scope should I use in this case?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a view model where I use `viewModelScope` and everything works perfect in there. Then, I have a class shared by many view models (injected in the constructor). Inside that class I need to call suspend methods and I don't know what's the correct coroutine scope to use.

Right now I'm using `GlobalScope` but it doesn't sound quite right, I feel the scope of execution should be guided by the owner of this class instance (the view model). I don't understand why if view model uses `viewModelScope` this injected class should use `GlobalScope` if not necessary.

I'm quite new with Kotlin so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Depends on your use case. If the injected dependency should be in control, you should probably just call `CoroutineScope()` and use that. If the callers should be in control, all you need is `suspend` functions, possibly calling `coroutineScope {}` so you have access to scope functions. Either way, you are correct that using `GlobalScope` is wrong.

Comment: How are you injecting the class into ViewModels? The class that instantitates this shared class should also be responsible for cleaning it up. You can create a SupervisorScope inside the shared class, and expose a `release()` function that cancels the scope for its instantiating class to call when it's done.

Comment: @Jorn can you please expand "f the callers should be in control, all you need is suspend functions, possibly calling coroutineScope {} so you have access to scope functions". This is my first approach to Kotlin and I'm still learning.

Comment: @Tenfour04: I'm injecting references using Hilt.

Comment: @StackOverflower In your dependency: `suspend fun callMe() = coroutineScope { /* can call functions like launch here */ }`, then in your caller `someLocalScope.launch { dependency.callMe() }`. This will cause the whole chain to be cancelled if the *caller's* scope is cancelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only scope that can be shared between multiple ViewModels is the Singleton scope, so I assume the class in question is provided as such (otherwise you'd get a new instance for every ViewModel and then it's fine to use the VM scope). What you could do is creating a shared supervisor job, here's how I usually go about that:

```
@Singleton
open class CoroutinesDispatchers @Inject constructor() {
    open val IO: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
    open val Main: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main
    open val Default: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
    open val Unconfined: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined
}
```

^^ this one allows you to swap out the dispatchers in unit tests and follows the general recommendation not to use `Dispatchers.XX` directly. The actual scopes are provided as follows:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class DefaultCoroutineScope

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class UICoroutineScope

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object CoroutinesModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @DefaultCoroutineScope
    fun defaultCoroutineScope(dispatchers: CoroutinesDispatchers): CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(
        SupervisorJob() + dispatchers.Default
    )

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @UICoroutineScope
    fun uiCoroutineScope(dispatchers: CoroutinesDispatchers): CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(
        SupervisorJob() + dispatchers.Main
    )

}
```

Then you just inject the scope you need - you could of course use other dispatchers (e.g. IO) or change the dispatcher after launching a coroutine according to your needs. Basically what you get is *a kind of a GlobalScope* in a more controllable manner.

Comment: My Kotlin experience is very limited. Can you please show me how you inject and use this? I understand it would be `@UICoroutineScope val coroutineScope CoroutineScope` or `@ DefaultCoroutineScope val coroutineScope CoroutineScope` on constructor to inject it

Comment: yep, that's it! Hilt makes this pretty straight-forward. You would use `uiScope.launch { ... }` for anything that must run on the main thread and `defaultScope.launch { ... } ` for everything else (the names are just a suggestion)